# I have problems setting height for the chart, I want to set the plot height of all charts equally, how to do it?

Tags: plot, highcharts

pls check link.  I want to set the plot height of all charts equally, how to do it?
link here: ***jsfiddle.net/doanvh/vqn24y5w/14/*** (type ***http://*** left link)

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqdF7.png)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can find the highest value of the `height` among all charts and based on the found value, modify the rest. I have modified your example a little bit by adding a function (look for the updatePlotHeights function between script tags, HTML tab) that performs a simple calculation that makes all charts' heights equal. Also I have decreased charts' widths in order for you to display them horizontally to compare them.

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qbs6k3Lp/

Comment: Thanks so much, best wish for you! 